# Pandas - non overlapping group members

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id  start   end     score
C1  2       592     157
C1  179     592     87
C1  113     553     82
C2  152     219     350
C2  13      70      319
C2  13      70      188
C2  15      70      156
C2  87      139     130
C2  92      140     102
C3  18      38      348
C3  20      35      320
C3  31      57      310
C4  347     51      514
```

The data is ordered by the id and the score.

id represents a sequence of DNA.

Start and end represent positions in id and I would like to keep non overlapping slices and from the overlapping only the highest ranked:

```
id  start   end score
C1  2   592 157
C2  152 219 350
C2  13  70  319
C2  87  139 130
C3  18  38  348
C4  347 51  514
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shorter and meets all requirements. You need:

1. A way to check overlap
2. A way to group your data by ID
3. A way to grab the best from each group, after checking overlap.

This does all of those, cheating by using logic and `groupby`

```
# from Ned Batchfelder
# http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201310/range_overlap_in_two_compares.html
def overlap(start1, end1, start2, end2):
    """
    Does the range (start1, end1) overlap with (start2, end2)?
    """
    return end1 >= start2 and end2 >= start1

def compare_rows(group):
    winners = []
    skip = []
    if len(group) == 1:
        return group[['start', 'end', 'score']]
    for i in group.index:
        if i in skip:
            continue
        for j in group.index:
            last = j == group.index[-1]
            istart = group.loc[i, 'start']
            iend = group.loc[i, 'end']
            jstart = group.loc[j, 'start']
            jend = group.loc[j, 'end']
            if overlap(istart, iend, jstart, jend):
                winner = group.loc[[i, j], 'score'].idxmax()
                if winner == j:
                    winners.append(winner)
                    skip.append(i)
                    break
            if last:
                winners.append(i)
    return group.loc[winners, ['start', 'end', 'score']].drop_duplicates()

grouped = df.groupby('id')
print grouped.apply(compare_rows)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just modified a little the istart, iend, jstart, and jend value assignation because sometimes the fragments of interest can be inverted.

`istart, iend = sorted([group.loc[i,'start'],group.loc[i,'end']])`

`jstart, jend = sorted([group.loc[j,'start'],group.loc[j,'end']])`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version that

- Add a column to compute the range, and uses the fact that the largest range can nest anything with a smaller range
- Sorts on the range column to exploit this property
- Removes any that are nested in each pass, so that they aren't compared multiple times.

This is just setup to make running easy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import StringIO as sio


data = """
id,start,end,score
C1,2,592,157
C1,179,592,87
C1,113,553,82
C2,152,219,350
C2,13,70,319
C2,13,70,188
C2,15,70,156
C2,87,139,130
C2,92,140,102
C3,18,38,348
C3,20,35,320
C3,31,57,310
C4,347,51,514"""

data = pd.read_csv(sio.StringIO(data))
```

The next block does the work.

```
data['range'] = data.end - data.start
data.sort_values(['id','range'])
g = data.groupby('id')

def f(df):
    keep = []
    while df.shape[0] > 0:
        widest = df.iloc[0]
        nested = (df.start >= widest.start) & (df.end <= widest.end)
        retain = df.loc[nested]
        loc = retain.score.values.argmax()
        keep.append(retain.iloc[[loc]])
        df = df.loc[np.logical_not(nested)]
    return pd.concat(keep,0)

out = g.apply(f).drop('range', 1)
out.index = np.arange(out.shape[0])
```

Using the data above, out

```
In[3]: out

Out[3]: 
   id  start  end  score
0  C1      2  592    157
1  C2    152  219    350
2  C2     13   70    319
3  C2     87  139    130
4  C2     92  140    102
5  C3     18   38    348
6  C3     31   57    310
7  C4    347   51    514
```

Comment: Suppose data aren't nested, but only partially overlap? `nested = (df.start >= widest.start) & (df.end <= widest.end)` is then too strict I think. Still, much more efficient than mine!

Comment: I thought about that case, but didn't think the question had enough detail to determine the set of rules of how to resolve cases of non-overlapping.  For example, suppose you have [1,5] with val=1, [1,3] with val=3 and [2,4] with val=3.  In the case, clearly either [1,3] or [2,4] are better than [1,5], but since these two don't overlap, I was sure what should be returned.

Comment: I agree about the tiebreaking issue, just thought I'd raise the question