# Python 3: remove overlaps in table

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, filtering

I have a table (simplified output from a program), that I need to filter:

```
id   hit from   to value
A   hit1    56  102 0.00085
B   hit2    89  275 0.00034
B   hit3    240 349 0.00034
C   hit4    332 480 3.40E-15
D   hit5    291 512 3.80E-24
D   hit6    287 313 0.00098
D   hit7    381 426 0.00098
D   hit8    287 316 0.0029
D   hit9    373 422 0.0029
D   hit10   514 600 0.0021
```

For each id, the `df` should be sorted by `from` and, if there are overlapping hits, keep the one with the lower `value`.

So far, this is my code, which does first the starting by `from` then by `value`:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("table", sep='\s+', names=["id", "hit", "from", "to", "value"])
df.sort_values(['from', "value"]).groupby('id')
```

But how do I check for the overlap (`from` to `to`) & remove the one with the *higher* score?

This is my expected output:

```
id   hit from   to valu
A   hit1    56  102 0.00085
C   hit4    332 480 3.40E-15
D   hit5    291 512 3.80E-24
D   hit10   514 600 0.0021
```

Please note, that `id B` has two overlapping hits with equal value, therefore both entries are to be kicked out.

Comment: can you put some overlapping values in the test data?

Comment: Can you explain overlapping?

Comment: sorry if that was unclear. Consider `from` and `to` as coordinates. Therefore `A` doesn't have any overlapping hits because it is the only hit, whereas `B` has an overlap in the coordinates 240 to 275. And `D` has 5 overlapping hits of which 1 has to be selected based on lowest `value`, but the last `hit10` has no overlap with the others of `D`.

Comment: It seems that under your logic, id 'D', hit 'hit5' should be dropped, but you have it in your example. Am I reading your logic correctly?

Comment: The hit with the LOWER value should be kept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first we introduce a unique `ID` and use [`pd.Interval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Interval.html):

```
df['ID'] = range(df.shape[0])
df['Interval'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(x['from'], x['to'], closed='both'), axis=1)
```

After this we join df on itself and calculate the overlapping parts:

```
columns = ['id', 'Interval', 'ID']
connected = df[columns].merge(df[columns], on='id')
connected['Overlap'] = connected.apply(lambda x: x['Interval_x'].overlaps(x['Interval_y']), axis=1) 
connected = connected.loc[connected['Overlap'] == True, ['id', 'ID_x', 'ID_y']]
```

Now we know which IDs overlap but we do not know which of them build a connected component. In general this cannot be done by a simple algorithm like reodering but a bit [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) helps. So we build a graph

`graph = connected.groupby(['id', 'ID_x']).agg(list)`

and calculate the connected components via [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

```
def connections(graph, id):
    def dict_to_df(d):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[d.keys(), d.values()], index=['ID', 'Subgraph']).T
        df['id'] = id
        return df[['id', 'Subgraph', 'ID']]

    def dfs(node, num):
        visited[node] = num
        for _node in graph.loc[node].iloc[0]:
            if _node not in visited:
                dfs(_node, num)

    visited = {}
    graph = graph.loc[id]
    for (num, node) in enumerate(graph.index):
        if node not in visited:
            dfs(node, num)

    return dict_to_df(visited)

dfs = []
for id in graph.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    dfs.append(connections(graph, id))

conns = pd.concat(dfs)
```

`conns` holds the connected components and we can put things together:

`data = df.merge(conns[['Subgraph', 'ID']], on=['ID'])`

Our last task is to choose the rows we want to keep:

```
def select_min(x):
    m = x['value'].min()
    if len(x) > 1 and (x['value'] == m).all():
        return -1
    else:
        return x['value'].idxmin()

selected = data.groupby(['id', 'Subgraph'])['value', 'ID'].apply(select_min)
selected = selected[selected >= 0]
```

Now we are done:

```
print(df.loc[df.ID.isin(selected), :].drop(columns=['ID', 'Interval']))
  id    hit  from   to         value
0  A   hit1    56  102  8.500000e-04
3  C   hit4   332  480  3.400000e-15
4  D   hit5   291  512  3.800000e-24
9  D  hit10   514  600  2.100000e-03
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat explanation! I am getting an `AttributeError: ("'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object has no attribute 'overlaps'", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: Which `pandas` version (`pd.__version__`) are you using? With 24.1 everything works fine.

Comment: Well, I'm very glad!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind multiple lines in your code, something like this should work, I guess... (python newbie here...) [source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.sort_values(['from', "value"]).groupby('id')
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'value'], keep=False, inplace=True)
```

"*keep*" parameter is set to false because you don't want the dublicate rows at all.

**Which results in:**

```
  id    hit from   to     value
0  A   hit1   56  102   0.00085
3  C   hit4  332  480  3.40E-15
4  D   hit5  291  512  3.80E-24
9  D  hit10  514  600    0.0021
```

**And to get rid of messy index column:**

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

**Which results in:**

```
  id    hit from   to     value
0  A   hit1   56  102   0.00085
1  C   hit4  332  480  3.40E-15
2  D   hit5  291  512  3.80E-24
3  D  hit10  514  600    0.0021
```

PS: This is my first time giving an answer so, please be gentle. And also, I'm still learning English.

Comment: Solution is bad, there is no removed overlaping, unfortuantely data are not MCVE, so get output like need OP. But with another data solution failed.

Comment: I agree, this solution is only removing duplicate values unfortunately...

Comment: Then maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658478/10183880) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657522/pandas-non-overlapping-group-members) might be helpful? @Saraha

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D' ,'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                  'hit': ['hit1', 'hit2', 'hit3','hit4', 'hit5','hit6', 'hit7','hit8', 'hit9','hit10', 'hit11'],
                  'from': [56,89,240,332,291,287,381,287,373,514, 599],
                  'to':[102,275,349,480,512,313,426,316,422,600, 602],
                  'value': [0.00085,0.00034,0.00034,3.40E-15,3.80E-24,0.00098,0.00098,0.0029,0.0029,0.0021, 0.002]})

overlapMask =  df.sort_values(by = 'from')\
                 .groupby('id')\
                 .apply(lambda x: np.where(x['from'] < x['to'].shift(), 0 , 1).cumsum())\
                 .reset_index()

df['Mask'] = np.concatenate((overlapMask[0].values))


df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['id','value'], keep = False, inplace = True)


df.sort_values(by = 'value')\
  .groupby(['id', 'Mask'])\
  .head(1)\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop(['Mask', 'index'],axis = 1)\
  .sort_values(by = 'id')


    id  hit    from  to    value
2   A   hit1    56  102 8.500000e-04
1   C   hit4    332 480 3.400000e-15
0   D   hit5    291 512 3.800000e-24
3   D   hit11   599 602 2.000000e-03
```

So my solution uses a mask to check for overlap. By sorting the 'from' values, and checking if the next 'from' value is less than the previous 'to' value. The np.inf is to just make sure the first value will always be a 0 in a grouping.

We then make the mask its own column in our df. We then group by everything we need to, drop any duplicates, reset the index, then finally drop our mask.

Comment: I am getting a `TypeError: shift() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'`

Comment: This seems to be new in pandas 0.24.0, check your pandas version. I also just checked, you seem to not need the fill_value there, so you can just delete it. What happens is the first value for everything is just 1 instead of 0, but that doesn't effect the grouping of the mask.

Comment: @Saraha, did you give it a try again?

Comment: I tried it adding another line to the table (`D hit11 599 602 0.0002`). Unfortunately, this is somehow not considered by the code because I am getting a wrong output...

Comment: Your right, there was a bug I missed, I fixed the code it should work properly now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort id == 'D'

```
    id  hit from    to  value
5   D   hit6    287 313 9.800000e-04
7   D   hit8    287 316 2.900000e-03
4   D   hit5    291 512 3.800000e-24
8   D   hit9    373 422 2.900000e-03
6   D   hit7    381 426 9.800000e-04
9   D   hit10   514 600 2.100000e-03
```

Overlapping will be:

- hit 6, 8, and 5 = keep 5 bc lowest value
- hit 9 and 7 = kepp 7
- hit 10 is alone keep it?

Comment: Not quite. Hit 6,8,5 overlap as you say, but hit 9 overlaps with hit 5 and hit 7 overlaps with hit 9. Here, choose the one (out of 5) that has the lowest value. Hit 10 has no overlap at all, so keep.

Comment: The logic is quite complicated and I have not have time to go over it this week. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the implementation if you go group by group then row by row is fairly straightforward.There doesn't seem to be a way in pandas to write a function that operates on multiple rows and columns at once in an effective way.

```
def strip(group):
    non_overlapping=[]
    overlapping = [list(group.itertuples())[0]]
    end = list(group.itertuples())[0].to
    for row in list(group.itertuples())[1:]:
        if row[3]<=end:
            overlapping.append(row)
            if row.to > end:
                end = row.to
        else:
            non_overlapping.append(reduce_overlap(overlapping))
            overlapping=[row]
    non_overlapping.append(reduce_overlap(overlapping))
    return non_overlapping
```

The algorithm for searching is fairly straightforward you have a sorted nonempty group of rows that all have the same ID. You goto first element and take the end. all subsequent rows that have starts before that are overlapping and if they end after we make their end our new end value.

```
def reduce_overlap(overlapping):
    overlapping= sorted(overlapping,key=lambda x: x.value)
    if len(overlapping)==1 or overlapping[0].value != overlapping[1].value:
        return overlapping[0]
    else:
        return []
```

To find the value to return we sort by the value returning nothing if by chance their are two of the same value.

Edit:
Here is function that applies it to the whole dataframe that I haven't tested.

```
def nonoverlapping(df):
  return df.Dataframe.from_records([strip(group) for name,group in df.sort_values(['from', "value"]).groupby('id')])
```

Comment: How do I apply the function `strip(group)` to the whole dataframe?

Comment: you don't you apply it group by group. Their is still some reworking to make it recombine into a df. I looped over them group by group with ```for name,group in df.sort_values(['from', "value"]).groupby('id'):
    print(strip(group))```